# How did my Artifactory generic and docker repos suddenly change type/version?

Tags: artifactory, docker-registry

We have been running Artifactory (currently version 6.9.0) in EC2 for months now with no problems.  This was originally a licensed instance of Enterprise Artifactory that we let lapse (intentionally).

Last week we started getting a storage warning (we use cluster-s3 storage) that we were at 95% utilization (which disables uploads) so we started cleaning up old artifacts (i.e., binaries, Docker images) to get the storage down.  We got it down for a while, but it crept back up -- high enough this time that we couldn't ssh in, so we rebooted the machine via the EC2 Console.
It came right back with no obvious problems.  Then we deleted a generic repository that someone had set up as a back up of another system (300GB) which bought us back plenty of space.

Today, a number of our builds started failing because the step to push the artifact to Artifactory failed.  Upon further investigation, a number of our "generic" repositories are now appearing (and behaving) as "Docker" repositories.  Further, a number of our v1 Docker repositories are now reporting as v2 Docker repos and blocking standard pushes from v1 clients.

The docs are pretty clear that we can't change the repo type, and I'm not seeing a way to migrate back to v1 from v2 Docker repos.  I'm currently exporting one of the repos to see if we can import it as the right type.

Any idea what happened here?  Did something get corrupted in the database?  What can I even start to check?

Comment: looks like the DB got corrupted somehow or the artifactory.config.latest.xml got corrupted, the configurations are stored on DB and I highly doubt DB caused this issue as there is no such to change a repository type manually or there were already repositories of generic and docker existed and could have got overrriden.

Comment: @shane-o is it possible that someone (an admin) have made changes directly on the configuration XML (via the UI or REST API)?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky Possible, but highly unlikely.